# Rstudio: pi^e vs e^pi

Tags: r

I am trying to compare the value between pi^e and e^pi using rstudio. I get the error "e" not found. I thought e and pi were universal values and could be called at will to be compared. I am fairly new to studio so any info is appreciated thank you

Comment: Just do `e = exp(1)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458536/r-programming-how-do-i-get-eulers-number

Comment: Why use RStudio at all? It is much more interesting to determine `max(pi^e,e^pi)` without a computer or other computational aid.

Comment: Actually, R does not have many built-in constants and pi is the only mathematical one (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Constants.html). So you need to create them yourself, as @Jonas suggested.